# A word for a person who blindly believes what is taught in school

Tags: word-request

Is there an English word for a person who blindly believes what is taught in school, information disseminated by mainstream media, what Wikipedia says, etc.? If there is such a word, I would like to put it in the blank in the following sentences:

> Reiko is not a _____ at all. She is highly skeptical of Darwinism and
> the Big Bang theory.

Comment: What's wrong with those theories?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326907/what-do-you-call-someone-who-is-easily-influenced  Note that in English I think we would use an adjective rather than a noun.

Comment: Kids who seriously think they know better than their teachers because they'd rather believe clickbaity websites are what we in the UK call ["numpties"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/numpty). Oh, wait! OP thinks it's *numpties* who believe in Evolution rather than Fairy Godmothers!

Comment: The Big Bang is the prevailing cosmological model for the universe. How are *schoolchildren* qualified to come up with credible alternatives?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - did you read or hear about the Brazilian school child who, it is claimed, has come up with a 'new' method of finding square roots that was, in fact, first described by the Babylonians? And is fairly trivial.  But that doesn't put off the media, social or otherwise.

Comment: @FumbleFingers because they are not tainted by 'received wisdom' or yet understand 'career suicide'. It is young minds who are free thinkers.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: 'new' method? Looks like the kind of trivial "convergent approximation" method millions of people would come up with independently, if they didn't have a calculator to hand!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey She didn't say they were wrong. She said, "highly skeptical". Here are two of the links she gave to me. https://www.discovery.org/m/securepdfs/2023/05/Scientific-Dissent-List-05012023-2.pdf https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPvdOVrPIZ0

Comment: @MichaelHarvey remember to use the comment thread to suggest improvements to the question, and not discuss the nonsense that is creationism.

Comment: The question should be rephrased: “*What is the name for a young person who **doesn't believe anything** that is taught to them?*”

Comment: I guess the dividing line between praiseworthy scepticism and idiotic contrarianism can be hard to make out sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

While I think your example is poor, there are a number of pejorative terms for a person who is easily deceived:

> Patsy, sheeple, sucker

In particular "Sheeple" (a portmanteau of "sheep" and "people") is a recent word for people who (it is claimed) are deceived or easily misled by government and big-business.

However, most of the people who use the word "sheeple" seem to be conspiracy theorists.

All the words are *casual* or *slang* (and probably not appropriate for a school essay).  In more formal context you should use an adjective like "gullible" or "impressionable".

Comment: Also note, these choices have negative tone, ranging from disapproving to mocking. I'm not aware of a noun choice that would communicate what the OP is looking for with a neutral tone, the way "skeptic" works for the opposite.

Comment: An excellent answer. Accurate and exact.